# Ignoring diacritics/accents when searching

Tags: search

Is there a way to instruct Vim that I want to ignore diacritics/accents when searching? For example, I would like to be able to search for

```
kočička
```

by entering

```
/kocicka
```

The [`ignorecase`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'ignorecase') and [`smartcase`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'smartcase') options are very useful, but they do not seem to have anything to do with diacritics/accents.

Comment: Related: [`:h [[=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5B%5B%3D) and [`:h patterns-composing`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#patterns-composing).

Comment: Related feature request https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8026

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @muru mentioned in the [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/ignoring-diacritics-accents-when-searching#comment12095_7386), you could use an equivalence class (described in `:help /[[`) which seems to be a character class expression evaluated as a set of similar characters (i.e. are the same once you remove any accent/diacritic).

For example, to look for `kočička` and `kocicka` with the same pattern, you could use this:

```
ko[[=c=]]i[[=c=]]ka
```

where `[[=c=]]` is the equivalence class for the `c` character.

---

To automatically insert this character class whenever you hit `c` while performing a search, you could use this mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr> c getcmdtype() =~ '[?/]' ? '[[=c=]]' : 'c'
```

which can be broken down like this:

- `<expr>` type the evaluation of an expression
- `getcmdtype() =~ '[?/]'` test whether you're writing a backward or forward search
- `'[[=c=]]'` return the equivalence class for the `c` character if the previous test succeeded
- `'c'` return the `c` character otherwise

---

The previous mapping has 2 drawbacks:

1. it only covers the `c` character
2. it can make the pattern difficult to read

It could be improved by remapping `<CR>` like this:

```
cnoremap <CR> <C-\>e getcmdtype() =~ '[?/]' ? substitute(getcmdline(), '\a', '[[=\0=]]', 'g'): getcmdline()<CR><CR>
```

When you hit `<CR>` after writing a pattern for a search, the mapping will automatically replace all the alphabetic characters by their equivalence class counterpart.

---

The mapping for `<CR>` is similar to the previous mapping for `c`, except it doesn't use the argument `<expr>` but the system mapping `<C-\>e`.
`<expr>` allows you to insert the evaluation of an expression, while `<C-\>e` allows you to replace the whole command line with the evaluation of an expression.

Comment: Further, if you would like to go in the reverse direction, e.g., `/kočička` matches `kocicka`, then you can use `'[[:lower:][:upper:]]'` instead of `'\a'`. The alternatives `'[:alpha:]'` and `'\I'` don't seem to work with multi-byte characters; however, `'[^[:punct:]]'` seems to work (though I'm less sure), and I would guess building your own equivalence class (e.g., `'[А-яЁё]'`) as well.

Comment: I wish there was a setting for that. While using [[=c=]] works but mistype means you need to click backspace 7 times. As well readability suffers.

Answer (score 1):

I have found you can use ranges with accented letters just as you do for standard letters. This works well enough for spanish. E.g. You can use `/[á-ú]` just like `/[a-z]`. You can even combine them: `/[a-zá-ú]` to include both standard letters and accented vowels.

If you want to know what you are exactly including in your search with `/[á-ú]` range, I suggest to open a new buffer in Vim and enter the following:

```
" Put the first 1000 ascii charachters in the current line
:for i in range(1,1000) | call setline('.', getline('.') . nr2char(i)) | endfor

" Test the search expression
/[á-ú]
```

Inspiration for the code above: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12450/12510